# How can I calculate summated math questions without using some kind of computer script or program?

Tags: summation

For example, how can I find the sum of $\frac 1 {(2 + n) \cdot (3 + n)}$ + ... for $n = 0$ to $n = 97$
 i.e.

$$\frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \frac 1 {3 \cdot 4} + ... + \frac 1 {99 + 100}$$

Comment: For some sums like this there is a trick that allows you to convert the sum to a known sum. There is a trick here

Comment: @SujaanKunalan My bad. Deleting the comment.

Comment: Thank you for getting the parentheses right.  This is rarer than it should be.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$\frac{1}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1}$$

Hence, your second series can be rewritten as

$$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} + ...$$

terminating, of course, at an appropriate point.

---

Similarly,

$$\frac{1}{(2 + n)(3 + n)} = \frac{1}{2 + n} - \frac{1}{3 + n}$$

Comment: @Jason: It's worth noting in general that there is no way to find such short formulae for summations in terms of just the boundary values (in your case 0 and 97). In many others there might be a method, but it is extremely difficult.